# matlab selecting elements from a 2d array

Tags: matlab

I have a 601 X 1600 matlab array (time x trials). I want to create a separate array  by discarding the trials that exceed the criterion value of 100. ie, the resulting array should be 601 x n in size. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation around find? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html

Comment: Better reference here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Comment: Are you sure you can still have n columns for all rows after discarding values > 100?

Comment: n will be equal to or  less than 1600

Answer (score -1):

You have two options here. One is use `find` as [bzier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9526448/bzier) pointed out.

The other one I'm suggesting here is based on [logical operation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html) which is faster.

```
m_transposed = m'; % m is your 601*1600 matrix
mask = m_transposed<=100; % a logical matrix 
m = m_transposed(mask); % this creates a vector, the values of which are <= 100
m = reshape(m, [], 601)'; % reshape the vector into a 601*n matrix.
```

You can also combine the four lines into two lines:

```
m_transposed = m';
m = reshape(m_transposed(m_transposed<=100), [], 601)';
```

Note that if the number of elements to be discarded is different from row to row, the above code will not work, because some rows will have less number of elements left and you cannot form a 601*n matrix. If this is the case, you have the option to fill empty spaces in the matrix with zeros or [`nan`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html?s_tid=doc_ta):

```
mask = m>100;
m(mask) = nan; % replace values > 100 with nans.
m(:,sum(mask)==size(m,1)) = []; % delete columns whose values are all nans.
```

### Update

Not sure why my answer got a downvote. Maybe I didn't mention the `find` approach? Just replace

`mask = m_transposed<=100` with `mask = find(m_transposed<=100)` or

`mask = m>100` with `mask = find(m>100)`

Comment: Don’t worry too much about a single downvote. Some people downvote answers to questions they deem “bad”. That said, I think OP wants to discard whole columns from the matrix (trials are the columns). What it means for a column to exceed 100 is anyone’s guess, though. OP hasn’t been back since posting the question 2 days ago.